# Problems creating an index

Tags: mysql, database

The question is:

Write the `SQL statement` to create an `index` on the `city table` for the attribute `CountryCode`. Name the index `CountryCode_idx`.

So my statement is:

```
CREATE INDEX city_name_countrycode_idx ON city (name, countrycode);
```

but the problem is, when I try to drop the index in the next question using statement

```
DROP INDEX city_name_countrycode_idx;
```

I get a syntax error expecting ON 
and then I try making a statement called:

```
DROP INDEX city_name_countrycode_idx ON city;
```

but my statement affected 0 rows apparently. Can someone tell me if my create index statement is correct and why my drop index statement isn't working?

Comment: Your second `DROP` syntax is fine. To check if structure was changed, you can do `SHOW CREATE table city` to see if it's present

Comment: if you dont have data in that table, then DROP INDEX would return 0 rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

> `DROP INDEX city_name_countrycode_idx;`
>    I get a syntax error expecting `ON` ...

As per documentation on [*`DROP INDEX Syntax`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-index.html):

```
Name: 'DROP INDEX'  
Description:  
Syntax:  
DROP INDEX index_name ON tbl_name  
    [algorithm_option | lock_option] ...  

algorithm_option:  
    ALGORITHM [=] {DEFAULT|INPLACE|COPY}  

lock_option:  
    LOCK [=] {DEFAULT|NONE|SHARED|EXCLUSIVE}
```

`DROP INDEX` drops the index named `index_name` from the table `tbl_name`.

**Conclusion**:

Hence to drop an index, you *must* use table name on which the index was created.

And for your index `city_name_countrycode_idx` to be dropped you have to use the table name `city` on which the said index is created.

```
DROP INDEX city_name_countrycode_idx ON city;
```

Comment: The user uses the table name city in his query:

DROP INDEX city_name_countrycode_idx ON city;

Comment: @AmanAggarwal: I know tha index name is `city_name_countrycode_idx` and table name is `city`. I have shown an example on how the syntax should be. My answer also includes a solution on his index too.

Comment: Didn't get the solution .
is this is the solution - > "DROP INDEX city_name_countrycode_idx ON city;"  ?

Comment: Thats i told you, the user himself gives this query in his third row..
kindly check..   :)

Comment: @AmanAggarwal: Aman, please read entire question. See the last statement of question. *Can someone tell me if my create index statement is correct and why my drop index statement isn't working?* And hence I included a *Conclusion* in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

0 rows affected means no change in data . Although the index is dropped.
you can cross check by desc the table before and after dropping the index

Thanks